# Is there a way how to use constants without scope resolution?

Tags: c#, scope, constants

I really miss C `#define` in C#; in C# [#define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/yt3yck0x.aspx) reference says:

> The #define directive cannot be used to declare constant values as is
>   typically done in C and C++. Constants in C# are best defined as
>   static members of a class or struct. If you have several such
>   constants, consider creating a separate "Constants" class to hold
>   them.

So I'd like to have something like this:

```
class Constants {
  public static const int UP=0, DOWN=1, LEFT=2, RIGHT=3;
  ...
}

class Foo {
  public Foo(int dir) {
    // import Constants scope here (and some other classes) somehow
    if(dir==UP) ...
    // ...because this is far worse readable
    if(dir==Constants.UP)
  }
}
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? It seems to me that enumeration values are what you want to be using and not constants. Look into Enum instead is my advice

Comment: Class name `Directions` would make it more readable. In fact it might be a good idea to create several constant classes (or enums) for different purposes

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you not to use such generic word as *Constants* for class which holds all your constants. Because it does not give any context to constants you have. And I don't suggest to keep all constants in one class. Create small contexts for each set of related constants. And give appropriate name for each small context.

There is nice way to group related named constants in one context - enumerations. So, create enumeration for your direction constants and give descriptive name to that enumeration:

```
public enum MoveDirection
{
    Up,
    Down,
    Left,
    Right
}
```

Now `Up` is not [Pixar Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1049413/) - its move direction:

```
switch(direction)
{
     case MoveDirection.Up:
         // ...
}
```

Comment: Damnit Sergey! You got there first!

Comment: That's what I try to avoid: it is hard to read `direction3D[MoveDirection.UP][MoveDirection.LEFT][MoveDirection.LEFT]`, compare it to `direction3D[UP][LEFT][LEFT]`

Comment: @JanTuroň I think I need more context for your problem. What data type you use, and what UP and LEFT really mean. I would suggest that it's movement direction in XY, YZ and XZ planes. But then movement UP on XY means exactly same as movement RIGHT on YZ

Comment: True, that wasn't very bright example: to set a direction, two angles in XY and YZ planes are enough. But the point is that scope resolution can be annoying if used in multiple places in some complex structure, I just tried to narrow the problem.

Comment: @JanTuroň there is rule of thumb - the bigger scope of variable usage, the more descriptive variable name should be. If I would found variable LEFT in global scope of application, it would not be obvious what that variable mean. Having variables scoped and grouped explains purpose of variables to other developers. If you want to shorten some specific code, like getting some `direction3D` value, then you should explain context and purpose of that code (I recommend to use http://codereview.stackexchange.com for reviewing and improving code)

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use Enumeration (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

```
public enum Something 
{
   UP=1, 
   DOWN=2,
   ....
}
```

Then you can us it like.

```
if(dir==Something.UP)
```

Comment: That is what OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on top of your code:

```
using UP = Constants.UP;
```

then you'll be able to use

```
if (dir == UP) ...
```

Comment: This looks great, but I get errors when I try to code it. Can you please give some example?

Comment: The error is *Constants.UP is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'*